# try except IndentationError

Tags: python, shell, exception

What is wrong with my indentation?

```
>>> try:
        print("Hello World!")
    except:

  File "<pyshell#2>", line 3
    except:
          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Using IDLE Python 2.7.2, Shell; after the try statements I attempt to backspace to the proper indentation but instead it goes to the left margin and I must type 4 spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here no need any indentation, "except" statement must be at the top level (the same as try statement).

Comment: I see now, I thought it was top level but the ">>>" was misleading. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> try:
    print("hello")
except:
    pass

hello
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The “except” block can't be empty. So, your code must be:

```
try:
    print("Hello World!")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: He is typing this in the interpreter, so the `IndentationError` occurred before he could add the body of `except` clause.

Answer (score 0):

try same for the if/else

> > > if 34 in list:

```
    list = [43]

else

   File "<pyshell#67>", line 3
```

else

^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

then doing this simple

> > > if 34 in list:

```
    list = [43]
```

else:

```
list = [324]
```